# Can not install vagrant-librarian-chef on Window?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin

I am install vagrant-librarian-chef in window 7, but it appear this error:

> Installing the 'vagrant-librarian-chef' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
>   Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
>   reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> An error occurred while installing chef (12.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install chef -v '12.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Users/tuan/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/chef-12.8.1-universal-mingw32/acceptance/top-cookbooks/test_run/learn-the-basics-ubuntu/cookbooks/learn-the-basics-ubuntu/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/kitchen-learn-the-basics-ubuntu-learn-the-basics-ubuntu-default-ubuntu-1404

Pls help me fix that.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you try running `gem install chef -v '12.8.1'` first and what happens there? The [vagrant-librarian-chef](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/vagrant-librarian-chef) plugin is no longer actively maintained and was last working with Vagrant ~1.5 so you may need to look into a more recent and active solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue when using the 'ohai' ruby gem.  I tried running `gem install chef -v '12.8.1'` but received an error.  I fixed my problem by adding

```
gem 'chef-config', '~>12.7.2'
```

to my gemfile.

I looked at my gem dependency tree (`gem dependency`) and noticed the 'ohai' gem was trying to use chef-config 12.8, so I pinned it to an earlier version.